# How to create a DiffGram #SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement like below.

A client is sending his data(xml file) in a particular file format/structure and now he made few changes to the format (I guess he moved few field positions and added few fields/columns). What is the best way to compare the prior and revised file formats?

Is creating a DiffGram an option? If so, I'm unsure how to create one. Can anyone out there help me?

Comment: Won't a standard difftool like Tortoise diff or Windiff suffice?

Comment: Generate XML Schema or DTD and compare those

Comment: read both XML, sort on FieldName node, then compare

Comment: My first attempt was to load both versions into Visual Studio (or another tool with XML format and file compare abilities), format both files with the same settings and then compare the files like you'd compare two versions of a code file...